# como acceder a un atributo de un select con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un select que lo lleno desde mi base de datos,todo bien hasta ahi pero lleno tres parametros en mi select: uno es el value , otro parametro 2 y otro lo que se muestra. Lo que necesito es obtener  lo que se muestra por eso cree el parametro 2 para que pueda obtenerlo por jquery.

les paso un imagen de como carga mi select

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito obtener lo que se muestra o el parametro 2

les paso el jquery

```
 function elegirsaldo(){
        var saldo = $(this).attr("parametro2");
        alert(saldo);
     }
```

pero me sale undefined

espero su ayuda gracias

Comment: comparte el código de tu html, para que otros desarrolladores podamos ayudarte más facilmente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obtener dicho atributo , tendrá que acceder a la opción seleccionada , más no al `select` en sí,  aunque este es necesario para realizar la acción anterior.
Además en su ejemplo el `this` no hace referencia al elemento `select`. si quiere que haga referencia podría pasar `this` desde el `html` y recibirlo en la función

```js
function elegirsaldo(el){ // recibimos por parametro el elemento select
   // obtenemos la opción seleccionada .
  var saldo = $('option:selected', el).attr('parametro2');
  console.log(saldo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="idgiftpro" onchange="elegirsaldo(this);">
  <option value="0" parametro2="0">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="1"  parametro2="10">50</option>
  <option value="2"  parametro2="20">100</option>
  <option value="3"  parametro2="30">200</option>
</select>
```

Otra forma sin hacer referencia desde el `html` al evento.

```js
$('#idgiftpro').change(function(e){
  var saldo = $('option:selected',this).attr('parametro2');
  console.log(saldo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="idgiftpro" >
  <option value="0" parametro2="0">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="1"  parametro2="10">50</option>
  <option value="2"  parametro2="20">100</option>
  <option value="3"  parametro2="30">200</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo !!

Answer (score 0):

Para cargar info a un elemento de HTML, lo mejor es asignarlo sobre su propiedad data.

```
<select id="idgifftpo" onchange="elegirsaldo(this)">
    <option value="0" data-parametro2="0">--Selecionar--</option>
    <option value="1" data-parametro2="50.00">Uno</option>
    <option value="2" data-parametro2="100.00">Dos</option>
</select>
```

Usando jQuery [puedes acceder directamente a data por medio de su nombre de data](https://api.jquery.com/data/), en este caso parametro2.

```
function elegirsaldo(sel){
        var saldo = $('option:selected', sel).data("parametro2");
        alert(saldo);
     }
```

O como atributo como lo estás buscando igual debe de funcionar.

```
function elegirsaldo(sel){
            var saldo = $('option:selected', sel).attr("data-parametro2");
            alert(saldo);
         }
```

Comment: gracias amigo !!

Answer (score 0):

Yo encontré otra forma:

```
var saldo = $('#idgifftpo>option:selected).attr("data-parametro2");
alert(saldo);
```

Comment: Bienvenido @Juan Alessandrini a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), favoreciendo así tus chances de obtener una buena recepción por parte de la comunidad.