# ¿Cómo acceder a un atributo de un select en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

encontré la respuesta a esta pregunta pero con jQuery [como acceder a un atributo de un select con jquery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119449/como-acceder-a-un-atributo-de-un-select-con-jquery) y he estado tratando de pasar la respuesta a javascript pero no lo consigo dejo el código aquí del enlace

```
function elegirsaldo(el){ // recibimos por parametro el elemento select
  // obtenemos la opción seleccionada .
  var saldo = $('option:selected', el).attr('parametro2');
  console.log(saldo);
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="idgiftpro" onchange="elegirsaldo(this);">
  <option value="0" parametro2="0">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="1"  parametro2="10">50</option>
  <option value="2"  parametro2="20">100</option>
  <option value="3"  parametro2="30">200</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `[selector].selectedOptions[0]` para obtener la opcion seleccionada (`selectedOptions` puede tener mas de un valor si es `multiple`)

```js
function elegirsaldo(el){ // recibimos por parametro el elemento select
  // obtenemos la opción seleccionada .
  var saldo = el.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('parametro2');
  console.log(saldo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="idgiftpro" onchange="elegirsaldo(this);">
  <option value="0" parametro2="0">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="1"  parametro2="10">50</option>
  <option value="2"  parametro2="20">100</option>
  <option value="3"  parametro2="30">200</option>
</select>
```

Comment: muchas gracias !!!